# SQL Server Express Version to Download

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server installed which shows version as

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)
```

I want to download SQL Server Management studio. I don not know if I have to download the 32 bit version or the 64 bit version.

When I go to the download page for SSMS 2014 I get the following options.

```
* Express 32BIT WoW64\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe

* Express 32BIT\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe

* Express 64BIT\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe
```

I want to know which version should I select for the above SQL Server Express edition.

Comment: You might want to download the 64 bit version to match your SQL Server as long as your computer supports 64bit

Comment: I will download the 64 bit version and check if it works - thanks.

Comment: @dwerty your question also includes answer ;-) hint: `x64`

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to download the 32 bit version, is if you have a 32 bit OS.

So if you have a 64 bit OS, download the 64 bit version (you can optionally download the 32 bit but why bother). If you have a 32 bit OS, you can only run the 32 bit version.

*Note that the bitness of the actual SQL server is irrelevant here.*

To talk to SQL 2012 you need to download a version of SSMS that is 2012 or later.

The latest version of SSMS (17.2) will talk to SQL 2012

So depending on your OS (if your computer is less than 5 years old it's almost definitely 64 bit), I suggest you download version 17.2, 64 bit (it actually only comes in 64 bit)

Note that the current SSMS download page at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms says

> > The 17.x generation of SSMS provides support for almost all feature areas on SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2017

I hope that makes sense.